# Split a file into lines

Tags: stream

I have a huge file (25 GB) consisting of the result of a BCP export procedure out of SQL Server.

Its contents look like this:

```
<row CodigoCaso="1"><Imagenes><root xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes"><cedulaantigua dt:dt="bin.base64"></cedulaantigua><formulariocara1 dt:dt="bin.base64"></formulariocara1><formulariocara2 dt:dt="bin.base64"></formulariocara2></root></Imagenes></row><row CodigoCaso="2"><Imagenes><root xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes"><cedulaantigua dt:dt="bin.base64"></cedulaantigua><formulariocara1 dt:dt="bin.base64"></formulariocara1><formulariocara2 dt:dt="bin.base64"></formulariocara2></root></Imagenes></row>
```

...and so on.

The rows do not have LF or CR after each `</row>`, so I need to insert an LF at the end of each `</row>`. How can achieve that, knowing that I can not load the file into a variable because of the size of the file?

Comment: Just read the file in chunks.

Comment: "The rows do not have LF or CR after each `</row>`, so I need to insert an LF at the end of each `</row>`" <-- this is a _non sequitur_. Please explain this supposed correlation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) read a random amount of bytes

2) append a CR/LF

3) if (not yet EOF) goto 1

4) Profit!

Comment: CR/LF in "random" places? Hmm, don't think so.

Comment: OMG it's XML. should have known.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the programming language, but you should be looking for some type of stream reader object to load a little bit of the file into memory at a time.

In C# it is the [System.IO.StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) class

In Java it is the [Java.io.BufferedReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) class